# Using binary trees in Haskell - Trying to use paths

Tags: list, haskell, binary-tree, branch

I'm struggling to go about this, so basically binary tree can be used as a database. Here, the leaves of a tree are either ND indicating no data, or Data d where d is a data item.

```
data Btree a = ND | Data a | Branch (Btree a) (Btree a)

data Dir = L | R

type Path = [Dir]
```

So one can give a path to a leaf by giving a list such as [L,R,L] which
indicates the leaf one arrives at by moving left, right, left from the root of the tree (there may be no such leaf).

What I'm trying to do is for example define something called e.g. extract where

```
extract :: Path  -> Btree a -> Error a
```

which given a path and a binary tree, outputs the data at the end of the path, and gives an error value when the path does not match any data. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What error occurs? Please write your attempt or we cannot help you.

Comment: But currently you do not show much effort yourself...

Answer (score 3):

It might help you get started to look at which cases you need to handle. You have two arguments, each of which has a small number of constructors:

1. The `Path` argument can be empty (`[]`) or not (`_:_`).
2. The `Btree a` argument can be empty (`ND`), have data (`Data _`), or be an interior node (`Branch _ _`).

Further, the return value isn't *always* an error; it could be a value of type `a`! The return value you probably have in mind is something like `Either e a` (where `e` is your error type, usually `String` but it could be an enumerated type like your `Dir` type) or even `Maybe a` if you just want to signal "no data found" with `Nothing`.

With that in mind, you have 6 cases for which your function should be defined:

```
extract :: Path -> Btree a -> Maybe a
extract [] ND = ...
extract [] (Data d) = ...
extract [] (Branch left right) = ...
extract (d:ds) ND = ...
extract (d:ds) (Data dat) = ...
extract (d:ds) (Branch left right) = ...
```

Now you have six simpler functions to define. Some are easy, some are less so, but this should give you somewhere to start, or at least refine what you are asking about.

Comment: @user2407038 Thanks. I noticed that when I was working up a complete solution, but forgot to fix it here.